# quicksort algorithm as WIKIPEDIA says in python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, wikipedia

In Wikipedia, there is a pseudo-code of quicksort algorithm:

So I tried to implement in python, but it does not sort anything.

```
def partition(A,lo,hi):
    pivot = A[hi]
    i=lo
    #Swap
    for j in range(lo,len(A)-1):
        if (A[j] <= pivot):
            val=A[i]
            A[i]=A[j]
            A[j]=val
            i=i+1
        val=A[i]
        A[i]=A[hi]
        A[hi]=val
    return(A,i)

def quicksort(A,lo,hi):
     if (lo<hi):
        [A,p]=partition(A,lo,hi)
        quicksort(A,lo,p-1)
        quicksort(A,p+1,hi)

A=[5,3,2,6,8,9,1]
A=quicksort(A, 0, len(A)-1)
print(A)
```

ORIGINAL: It does not throw an error so I do not no where I made a mistake.

UPDATE: It now goes into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't throw an error or print anything because there is no main program to run anything.  You indented what should be the main program, so that is now part of the **quicksort** function.

Also, this code *does* throw an error, because you left a comment in what you posted.  I'll clean up the code and edit your posting.

---

I corrected several code errors:

1. Removed "enter code here" text, which caused an obvious compilation error.
2. Corrected indentation, so that the last three lines are now your main program.
3. Corrected the main-program call: **quicksort** takes the bounds (subscripts) of the array, but you were passing in the array elements themselves.

That fixes your given problem.  You now have infinite recursion due to not handling the return values properly.  Also, your main program destroys the sorted array, since **quicksort** doesn't return anything.  The final print statement will give **None** as its result.

---

You haven't quite implemented the given algorithm.  The most important problem is the **for** loop's upper limit.

- Python loops do *not* include the end value.  Your given loop will run **j** through the values **lo** through **len(A)-2**, so you'll never treat the last value of the list.
- The upper limit given in Wikipedia is **hi**, not the list end.

Fix those, and you'll be close to a solution.

Also, I strongly recommend that you stick in a couple of tracing **print** statements, so you can see follow how the program works.  For instance, as the first statement of each function, print the function name and the input parameters.

Why do you return A from the function?  The Wikipedia algorithm doesn't do that, and it's not necessary: you altered the list in place.

Since you already know about multiple assignment, note that there's an easier way to swap two values:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Does this get you moving through the current problems, enough to get you back on the learning track you want?

Comment: Yes, thankyou But now, when fixed what you told me, it sorts, but nos quite well.The first array is the input, and in the end of the recursions I got none... why is that?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but now, it sorts not quite well. 
[5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1] --> input
[1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 6]--> recursions
[1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 6]
None--> ?

I do not know why at the end I get a none and I does not sort properly

Comment: I mentioned the last one in my comments.  **quicksort** has no return value; **None** is the default return.  Your mistake is to assign that value to A.  Just remove that statement, and you'll get your final output.

Comment: I can't help with the rest, because you didn't post the code.  *My* version of your code (after applying the suggestions in this answer) work nicely.  If you still have trouble, please post it as another question.